# MySQL Select `table_name`.`column_name` FROM multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Before anyone jumps at an answer here, `AS` is not it :-)

I have a query which I can simplify like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl1, tbl2
```

Both `tbl1` and `tbl2` have one column each named `id`, so the columns I get in the result of the query above is `id`, `id1`.

What I want to do is to return the column names as well, to give `id1` more meaning, ideally `tbl1.id`, `tbl2.id`

I can't use `AS` for this because this simplistic example doesn't explain what my query is, just what my issue is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to create an alias for the fields.

Comment: "An alias", you mean like AS?

Comment: There are very few situations where you should be using `SELECT *` (perhaps none)  - It causes ambiguity, and unnecessary network overhead. I know you have said that an alias is not the answer, but it is. You just need to rethink your question - i.e. instead of thinking how you can get `a.id` and `b.id` as column names, instead think why you need to use `SELECT *`

Comment: Yes, exactly. You shouldn't be using `SELECT *` in the first place, really.

Comment: In whatever your client language and library combination is, use a fetch method that locates columns by position rather than name. I've done it in the past using PHP to build a helper function to debug queries.

Comment: Because this dynamically built query could select from anywhere between 13 and 32 tables, and I want to var_dump the results for us developers to see. It will only ever select one row. Incidentally, this is just for us devs, so I am being lazy with the *, but thought it would be possible.

Comment: If it is dynamically built then dynamically add the columns names into the select, then you can dynamically add the alias.